# Play movie, image, or image sequence at specified time?

Tags: compositing-nodes, edit-mode, video

I have a live-action shot of someone holding a gun and fake-shooting. I want to add muzzle flashes with Blender's compositor, so I grab my muzzle flash stock image to overlay onto the shot. How can I make the flash appear at selected points in my shot?

So far the only thing I've found that seems close to this functionality is the Offset option on the Image node when an image sequence is selected, but this just skips frames, it doesn't place the sequence in time.

What I really want to do is decide when a Movie, Image or Image Sequence plays in my composition. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Image sequence

You can specify the frame one which the image sequence starts with the *Start frame* property of the the image node:

[image]

## Video file

I don't know of a way to do this with a video file in the compositor (there is no start frame option on the  movie clip node).

Note that this is a very trivial matter in the VSE ([Video Sequence Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage)) for still images, image sequences and video files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The movie clip editor stores a frame start and offset value in the clip properties. However it is per scene value meaning you cannot use multiple instances with various off sets.  A movie file can also be loaded in the image node so that you can access the frame and offset values but you can't use proxies or timecode.